# How to split the particular value from the cookie of string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got the cookie value here like

```
 a:3:{i:0;s:2:"87";i:1;s:2:"87";i:2;s:2:"87";}
```

when I am using cookie.
Here I need the value which is in double quotes.
Any one help me.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/function.unserialize)

```
<?php
$var='a:3:{i:0;s:2:"87";i:1;s:2:"87";i:2;s:2:"87";}';
print_r(unserialize($var));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 87
    [1] => 87
    [2] => 87
)
```

### Alternate Solution

```
<?php
preg_match_all('~"(.*?)"~',
    'a:6:{i:0;s:2:"87";i:1;s:2:"87";i:2;s:2:"87";i:3;s:2:"87";i:4;s:2:"88";i:5;s:2:"8‌​8";}',
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r(($out[0]));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => "87"
    [1] => "87"
    [2] => "87"
    [3] => "87"
    [4] => "88"
    [5] => "8‌​8"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string="a:3:{i:0;s:2:"87";i:1;s:2:"87";i:2;s:2:"87";}";
$its_a_match = preg_match('/"(.+?)"/', $string, $matches);
$whats_inside_the_quotes = $matches[1];
```

Comment: a:6:{i:0;s:2:"87";i:1;s:2:"87";i:2;s:2:"87";i:3;s:2:"87";i:4;s:2:"88";i:5;s:2:"88";} Only I can get 87 only. But I need all the values which is "Double quotes".

Comment: yes iterate on $matches[], it contains all $matches[2],$matches[3] and so on or try loop..